# ExternalIdentity.BootstrapContext always null

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

in my current application I am using Owin + Aspnet Identity along with Microsoft Live OAuth provider to handle authentication.

So far everything works fine except for my attempts to retrieve the remote token, in order to store it in my database.

I have found some documentation online which says to enable "saveBootstrapContext" in the web.config, and so I did:

```
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true"></securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
  </securityTokenHandlers>
</identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

I tried only on `identityConfiguration` then only on `securityTokenHandlerConfiguration` and then both together, but the result is always the same. In the following code `externalData.ExternalIdentity.BootstrapContext` is always null.

The SignIn method gets called inside the "ExternalLoginCallback" method which is called by the middleware.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;

// custom namespaces redacted
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

public class AuthManager : IAuthManager
{
    private readonly IUserBusinessLogic userBusinessLogic;

    public AuthManager(IUserBusinessLogic userBusinessLogic)
    {
        this.userBusinessLogic = userBusinessLogic;
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        IAuthenticationManager manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var externalData = manager.GetExternalLoginInfo();

        UserDto user = this.userBusinessLogic.GetUser(externalData.Login.LoginProvider, externalData.Login.ProviderKey);
        var token = ((BootstrapContext)externalData.ExternalIdentity.BootstrapContext).Token;

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = this.userBusinessLogic.AddUser(new UserDto(), externalData.Login.LoginProvider, externalData.Login.ProviderKey, token);
        }

        user.Token = token;

        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, UserData.FromUserDto(user).ToString())
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true
        };

        manager.SignIn(properties, identity);
    }
```

Some other posts here on SO said to try to restart IIS, restart the machine, empty the browser cookies and restart the browser. I tried all of that and still nothing. If I mock the token string everything else works properly.

Now I am clearly missing something but I can't find any clear documentation online.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes no help is the best help, as I've been forced to dig deeper and deeper, ultimately to find the solution.

Due premise is I was in total confusion and I was mixing three different technologies without understanding all implications.

My example used WIF configuration in web.config but then code side it was using Aspnet Identity atop of OWIN (which doesn't use web.config at all).

Once I got my ideas straight, I realized the following:

- WIF was totally unneeded, therefore I got rid of all that configuration (and of WIF altogether)
- Since my MS auth was being performed by the specific OWIN Middleware that handles it, I had to understand how to configure it to retrieve the token
- Aspnet Identity was being used only for the `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` static class, which provides some string constants. I kept it for simplicity sake but I could as well remove it.

So my refactored (and working) code looks like this. First of all, the Middleware configuration needed to get MS auth working along with the token, inside `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "myClientId",
    ClientSecret = "myClientSecret",
    Provider = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = context =>
        {
            // here's the token
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("AccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FirstName", context.FirstName));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("LastName", context.LastName));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Then the revisited `SignIn` method:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    IAuthenticationManager manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    var externalData = manager.GetExternalLoginInfo();

    UserDto user = this.userBusinessLogic.GetUser(externalData.Login.LoginProvider, externalData.Login.ProviderKey);

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = this.userBusinessLogic.AddUser(
            new UserDto
            { 
                FirstName = externalData.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "FirstName").Value,
                LastName = externalData.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "LastName").Value
            },
            externalData.Login.LoginProvider,
            externalData.Login.ProviderKey,
            // here's the token claim that I set in the middleware configuration
            externalData.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "AccessToken").Value);
    }

    var claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, UserData.FromUserDto(user).ToString()),
        new Claim("AccessToken", user.Token),
        new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName),
        new Claim("LastName", user.LastName)
    };

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        IsPersistent = true
    };

    manager.SignIn(properties, identity);
}
```

Maybe this was difficult just to me, but anyway here I am posting my solution hoping it can save some headaches and some days of swearing to some fellow developer.

Happy coding ^^